# How to delete duplicate keys in LinkedHashMap

Tags: android, grouping

i'm having a problem with duplicate keys in linkedhashmap , as far as i know that linkedhashmaps don't allow duplicate keys , i'm basically using the code to group data from api based on date ( so each date is key ) , this is the code i'm using

```
  private LinkedHashMap<String, List<Model>> groupDataIntoHashMaps(List<Model> mylist) {


        LinkedHashMap<String, List<Model>> groupedHashMap = new  LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (Model mymodel : mylist) {
            String hashMapKey = mymodel.getDate();

            if (groupedHashMap.containsKey(hashMapKey)) {

            } else {

                List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(mymodel);
                groupedHashMap.put(hashMapKey, list);
            }
            groupedHashMap.keySet().clear();
        }
        return groupedHashMap;
}
```

this is where im executing return type of my above method

```
modelList.add(new 

  Model(eventid,date,hometeam,awayteam,homelogo,awaylogo,homescore,awayscore,stadium,"Details",mytime));

 LinkedHashMap<String, List<Model>> groupedHashMap = groupDataIntoHashMaps(modelList);

 Log.d("TODO","MYGROUP" + groupedHashMap);/// in logcat , it shows duplicate keys

 for (String dates : groupedHashMap.keySet()) {

  Log.d("TODO","KEYS" + groupedHashMap.keySet());

  MyDateItem dateItem = new MyDateItem();

  dateItem.setDate(dates);

  consolidatedList.add(dateItem);

  for (Model mymodel : groupedHashMap.get(dates)) {

  MyGeneralItem generalItem = new MyGeneralItem();

 generalItem.setModel(mymodel);

 consolidatedList.add(generalItem);

   }

  ssadapter = new Ssadapter(consolidatedList, getContext());
  recyclerView.setAdapter(ssadapter);
```

after checking with the debugger , i found out that the grouphashmap is the one causing duplicate keys .
Any help would be appreciated guys , thank you.

PS : Here is the source of the code i'm using for grouping the data

https://krtkush.com/2016/07/08/android-recyclerview-grouping-data.html

Comment: are you sure youre not just missinterpreting debug results after putting in a List type as the value ?

Comment: Pretty sure , because i actually put grouphashmap.keyset(); in logcat message , and it showed clearly duplicate dates ( keys )

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **LinkedHashMap** don't contains duplicate keys, if there are duplicate keys then it must replace with fresh value.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linkedhashmap-class-java-examples/

If you still have them and wanted to delete convert them into different Map and then try to delete them.

Comment: Well i , called grouphashamp.keyset() , in Logcat , im having duplicate dates ( in my case dates are the key )